# Windows 10 V1511 - Mounting External Encrypted Drive Error "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: bitlocker, windows-10-v1511

I don't normally use encrypted volumes on my Windows 10 Professional machine but needed to do so today.  I normally use the drive on another system that runs Windows 7 Enterprise.

I discovered this problem when I initially connected the drive and missed the Windows 10 toast notification to unlocked the drive.  On Windows 7 when you right-click on the drive, you get an option to "Unlock Drive..." which then displays a password prompt.

When I did this same action on my Windows 10 machine I got the following context menu:

[image]

When I attempted to Open the drive, I got the following error message:

[image]

This PC:

[image]

At this point, I disconnected the drive, connected the drive again, and unlocked the drive through the toast notification.  At this point, I want to know the reason I could not unlock the drive through Windows Explorer.

Why can I only unlock the drive through the toast notification?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered the following support article about Windows 8.  [You cannot unlock a BitLocker-encrypted drive after you upgrade to Windows 8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2748266).  The article's subject was close enough to my problem, so I went ahead and verified the contents of the following two registry keys

```
Registry subkey:HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\unlock-bde Registry
```

and

```
Registry subkey: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\unlock-bde\command
```

What I discovered was interesting.

Instead Of:

> [image]
>
> and
>
> [image]
>
> REG_EXPAND_SZ value: %SystemRoot%\System32\bdeunlock.exe %1
>
> REG_EXPAND_SZ value: @%SystemRoot%\System32\bdeunlock.exe,-100

The values on the Windows 10 machine were the following:

> [image]
>
> and
>
> [image]
>
> REG_EXPAND_SZ value: %SystemRoot%\System32\BdeUnlockWizard.exe,-1
>
> REG_EXPAND_SZ value: @%SystemRoot%\System32\BdeUnlockWizard.exe,-100

Once I changed the keys to their correct value:

```
Registry subkey: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\unlock-bde\command
Registry entry: (Default)
REG_EXPAND_SZ value: %SystemRoot%\System32\bdeunlock.exe %1
```

and

```
Registry subkey:HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\unlock-bde
Registry entry: (Default)
REG_EXPAND_SZ value: @%SystemRoot%\System32\bdeunlock.exe,-100
```

Everything worked like it should:

[image]

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2748266)