# Why bitlocker options are gone from one of my drive?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

[image]

There is no such thing.

In managed bitlocker, everything is correct

Drive D has no difference with other drives. It is bitlocked. And unlocked, like usual.

[image]

Somehow the unlocked padlock icon doesn't show up on drive D but shows up on other drives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 V1511 - Mounting External Encrypted Drive Error "The parameter is incorrect"](https://superuser.com/questions/1009309/windows-10-v1511-mounting-external-encrypted-drive-error-the-parameter-is-inc).  While the issue is not exactly the same, my gut is telling me, the solution is identical.  Please provide the values of those registry keys mentioned in the answer.