# A Drive Becomes Not Accessible on Every Boot

Tags: windows, partitioning, bitlocker, check-disk

I have 2 physical disks connected to my PC, both of them are Bitlocker encrypted.
After I boot into Windows, I'm able to Bitlocker-unlock drive D:\ (2nd physical SSD connected via SATA 3) normally, but when I try to open the disk I get the error message:

```
Location is not available
D:\ is not accessible
The parameter is incorrect
```

A CMD command `chkdsk /f /r D:` ran as Administrator makes my drive usable again after an hour of waiting, yet after I restart PC the situation repeats.
What can be the cause of this and how I can fix it?
**Update:**`chkdsk /f D:` (without `/r`) takes 1 minute as opposed to 1 hour, after that command I'm able to use my drive, but until the next reboot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 V1511 - Mounting External Encrypted Drive Error "The parameter is incorrect"](https://superuser.com/questions/1009309/windows-10-v1511-mounting-external-encrypted-drive-error-the-parameter-is-inc)

Comment: I had the exact same problem years ago, you have a registry key that isn't correct, no amount of DISM/SFC will fix it.   I guarantee you my answer will solve your problem.

Comment: Nope. My registery values were already set to the values that you replaced.

Comment: Export all those keys, **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\**, into a text document and provide the text.

Comment: https://ghostbin.co/paste/6ssww
I don't know how to export not in hex though. Would that export work?

Comment: Alright; No; I am looking for something specific; What does the right click menu on the encrypted volume look like?  If you use the toast notification do you receive the error?

Comment: Unlock Drive... And once I put the password it changes to Open. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH7qA.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B6Gv.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0und.png The toast notification on the second screenshot accept the password and unlocks the drive, however, I get the error message `Location is not avaible` once I try to Open.