# D: disk not opening after BitLocker unlocking

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have a laptop with Windows-10 with 2 hard disks: a 128gb disk (C:) and another 1TB disk (which was divided into 3 partitions). Both disks had BitLocker activated.

The laptop remained unused for 3 months. On starting after that time, both disks were BitLocked and had to be unlocked. The C: disk is now working all right but the larger disk is not opening.

On trying to open the disk by right clicking, I get the error:

```
D:\ is not accessible
The parameter is incorrect
```

On trying to cd to that disk on command line, I get following error:

```
> d:
The volume does  not contain a recogniseed  file system. 
Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not  corrupted.
```

I have tried command `chkdsk D: /f`. It gave following output:

```
> chkdsk d: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted.
```

The disk on "disk management" application continues to show it to be BitLocked:

[image]

What is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Verify that this registry key is correct](https://superuser.com/questions/1009309/windows-10-v1511-mounting-external-encrypted-drive-error-the-parameter-is-inc).  Hopefully, you have the recovery key, since it might be required to decrypt the drive.

Comment: Which program should I use to correct registry keys? Regedit.exe or Regedit32.exe ?

Comment: Just use `regedit.msc` or whatever you normally would use.  I have never in 20 years had somebody asked that question.

Comment: Sorry, HaHa. Will try and give feedback soon.

Comment: Checked - both registry keys are correct.

Comment: Regedit.exe vs regedit32.exe came from first para on this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg-file-9c7f37cf-a5e9-e1cd-c4fa-2a26218a1a23

Comment: Seems like D wasn't unlocked. Could you try unlocking again?

Comment: I have unblocked it a number of times (message appears) but the disk management program still shows it as blocked.